# how to count a list of items in it

Tags: database, file

I am learning python from beginner and scratch, to do a basic read and write file and a simple count on a json file I got confused, for example.

1

```
  "091", 
  "10",
```

Comment: Your script isn't remotely valid Python. No colons after `for`/`if`/`else` statements, incorrect/missing indentation, attempts to write English text in the hopes that Python would know how to interpret it, binding variable names to imported module names, incorrect method names... have you read a basic Python tutorial?

Comment: Thanks, not really I assume I have to, I thought it would be easier.

Comment: @Zaeim Glancing at your profile it looks like you haven't accepted the answers to any of questions. If any of the answers to your questions have been properly answered it is polite (and preferable) to accept the best one.

Comment: Oh sorry I didnt know I have to accept them, I am appreciated of all people who check out my questions, answer them or even give negative point. Thank you for letting me know. I checked it, I dont know how can I accept those answers, could you tell me where in my profile I can find them and accept them?

Comment: @Zaeim To go to your profile click your picture in the top black bar. Part way down on the left side of that page there will be "x Questions" showing your 5 most recent. Click "Questions" to show all of them (which is paginated). From there you can select each question individually. After you've clicked on one of your questions, when looking at the answers, to the left of the answer (near the score) there should be an outline of a check-mark which when clicked will mark the answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your JSON file needs to have only a single array or object at the top level, not multiple objects:

```
[
  {
    "course": "CMPT 102 D1", 
    "instructor": "hamarneh", 
    "students": [
      "axc5", 
      "csf10", 
      "ctu1", 
      "nmw15", 
      "nsm12", 
      "ppy1", 
      "qtg13", 
      "tim1", 
      "tkd10", 
      "vhm8", 
      "vsv1", 
      "wps1", 
      "xup12", 
      "yqt6"
    ], 
    "title": "Scientific Cmpt.Prgm"
  },
  {
    "course": "CMPT 120 D1", 
    "instructor": "diana", 
    "students": [
      "axc5", 
      "cln6", 
      "dag5", 
      "fif11",
      ...
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Second, your example code has multiple syntax errors but I'm going to assume this is what you want:

```
import json

# Load JSON file.
with open('myfile.json') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

# Iterate over courses to find students.
for course in data:
    num_students = len(course['students'])
    print("Course {} has {} students.".format(course['course'], num_students))
```

This will output:

```
Course CMPT 102 D1 has 14 students.
Course CMPT 120 D1 has x students.
...
```

---

Or, if you wanted to count how many courses each student is taking you could do:

```
import json

# Load JSON file.
with open('myfile.json') as fh:
    data = json.load(fh)

# Iterate over courses to find students.
courses_per_student = {} # Maps student name to course count
for course in data:
    for student in course['students']:
        if student not in courses_per_student:
            courses_per_student[student] = 0
        courses_per_student[student] += 1

for student, courses in courses_per_student.items():
    print("Student {} is in {} courses.".format(student, courses))
```

This would output:

```
Student axc5 is in 2 courses.
Student csf10 is in 1 courses.
...
```

Comment: @Zaeim I updated my answer to include how to count the number of courses per student because I figured it would be easier to show it.